# calculate propotion of 1's of target variable within each level of categorical variable after dummying in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below data:

```
disc_off_m4 form
NaN         1
NaN         1
Y           1
Y           1
NaN         0
N           1
N           1
NaN         0
N           0
Y           0
Y           1
```

Where the form variable is the target variable.
I want to calculate the proportion of 1's within each level after dummying the categorical column disc_off_m4.

Code the generate the data:

```
import pandas as pd
df_prop = pd.DataFrame({'disc_off_m4':['NaN','NaN','Y','Y','NaN','N','N','NaN','N','Y','Y'],
                         'form' : [1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1]})

df_prop_cat = pd.get_dummies(df_prop.iloc[:,0])
frames = [df_prop_cat,df_prop['form']]
df_final = pd.concat(frames , axis = 1)
```

I want to store the proportions for each level in a dataframe, indexed on the dummy variables as below:

```
variable            proportion
disc_off_m4_N       0.67
disc_off_m4_Y       0.75
disc_off_m4_nan     0.50
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare column with `1` and aggregate `mean`, `True`s are processes like `1`s:

```
a = df_prop['form'].eq(1).groupby(df_prop['disc_off_m4']).mean().reset_index()
print (a)
  disc_off_m4      form
0           N  0.666667
1         NaN  0.500000
2           Y  0.750000
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df_prop['form'].eq(1))
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4     False
5      True
6      True
7     False
8     False
9     False
10     True
Name: form, dtype: bool
```

If only `1` and `0` values in `form` column:

```
a = df_prop.groupby('disc_off_m4', as_index=False)['form'].mean()
print (a)
  disc_off_m4      form
0           N  0.666667
1         NaN  0.500000
2           Y  0.750000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jezrael.. This doesn't deal with na values? I need to get the proportions within na level also as while using pd.get_dummies I do dummy_na = True. I am sorry I forgot to mention it in the question itself!

Comment: @ShuvayanDas - If use `groupby` then `NaN`s rows are removed, by design, so need `df_prop.fillna('nan').groupby('disc_off_m4', as_index=False)['form'].mean()` - repplace missing values to string

Comment: Thanks a lot!. :) I was just doing the astype(str) conversion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use groupby and mean().

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'disc_off_m4':['NaN','NaN','Y','Y','NaN','N','N','NaN','N','Y','Y'],
                         'form' : [1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1]})

df = df.groupby('disc_off_m4', as_index=True).mean()
df.index = df.index.name + '_' + df.index
print(df)

# Out put:
                     form
disc_off_m4_N    0.666667
disc_off_m4_NaN  0.500000
disc_off_m4_Y    0.750000
```

Comment: sum/count = mean?

Comment: For exactly the header line: `df.columns = pd.Index(['proportion'], name='variable')`